# Application Service Objects, should they contain methods which call domain service methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, poco

I am searching for an answer and I couldn't find any.

We have a Domain Layer which contains Services and POCOs. Then we have an ApplicationService Layer which contains Services which delegate the Domain Layer services and also maps the POCOs to upper layer objects.

The upper layer objects get  extended. For example we have products. I now have added a method, let it call "getPrice" which calls the "getPrice" method of the price service and passes its own productID as a parameter to retrieve the price of this product.
The price service gets introduced trough constructor injection into the product.

Now I am asking myself if this is a bad design. We only extend the objects in the application service, the ones in the domain are still POCOs.

Where are disadvantages in this concept?

Comment: Are you asking for reinforcement of your idea, or do you have specific technical concerns that you want to avoid here?  What is it that tells you this is bad design?

Comment: Someone pointed it out but wasn't able to point out the flaws. For me, this simplifies my code and I don't see which part of it is dangerous or wrong and I am searching for this part. If it isn't bad design I am fine with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an example of the relationship between an application service, domain service and domain entities, take a look [here](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/14/services-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/).

In a nutshell, application services encapsulate your domain and delegate behavior to domain objects by coordinating repositories and other services. This seems to be in accord with what you've described.

Where you seem to steer off course is with injecting services into the product entity. This is usually discouraged in DDD. Instead, if a particular behavior on an entity requires a service, pass the service to the method implementing the behavior. Some disadvantages of injecting services into entities are:

1. Your entity becomes more difficult to reason about.
2. It must become part of a dependency injection graph further complicating its use.
3. It violates SRP since there is likely only one behavior which requires the service.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing Domain-Driven Design. The overriding problem with DDD is that it is very easy to fall into an "anemic" design - meaning that you've got your domains, services, aggregate roots, repositories, etc.. but they only add unnecessary complexity instead of truly simplifying development.

A specific question -
Is your Product entity associated with the application, or is a Product really a domain entity? Does productID have meaning in the scope of the application? Your mention of the ID raises a yellow flag.

Separately:

As a matter of style, I like to keep surrogate keys (like productID) out of the application layer where it serves no purpose except to pass back and forth to the domain. I prefer to rely on natural keys once I get to the application layer.

Comment: The FrontEnd is an MVC project which needs the product id for the urls. The product is an domain object, which we map to the application service with automapper. In the applicationservice I have added methods like getPrice onto the object so that you can get the price by calling this method instead of calling another service. You also don't have to know the id of the product as it knows this already.

Comment: It sounds a-okay as long as your app service talks to the domain services only and never to the domain Product entity.

Comment: One more thought - you could still use the "product number" or "product code" to identify the product in the application layer and MVC land.